"file or directory is not a reparse point" in a network drive -- pyspark run locally on windows
Setting: I am running pyspark locally on a windows server and reading a csv from a shared network drive (that I have full access to). I setup my spark session and read the file as:
sparkdf = (
    spark
    .read
    .csv("path/to/file.csv", header=True)   
) 

Problem: Whenever I am doing some operation (could be basic operations like counting observations or aggregating some variable using groupBy), sooner or later it throws a The file or directory is not a reparse point error. Error snippet:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o239.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
Task 266 in stage 22.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
266.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 3975) (myusername executor driver):
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: path/to/file.csv: The file or
directory is not a reparse point

I suspect it has something to do with reading the file from the network drive because when I read the same file locally from my machine (as opposed to the network drive), it all works fine -- no error at all.
Is there a solution or a workaround to this issue? Can I somehow supply the path to the network drive that may prevent it from crashing?
